# HDFS ls shows file size 0 while Flume is writing the file

Tags: azure, hadoop, hdfs, azure-hdinsight

We are currently working on setting up an Apache Flume system which collects event data and writes it to files in our HDInsight HDFS cluster.  While verifying the initial setup `hdfs ls` displays 0 for the file size while Flume is writing to the file but when the file rolls (and the .tmp file extension is removed) the file size suddenly jumps up.

Is there some reason either with HDFS or HDInsight (or WASB) that the file size for a file would be 0 while Flume is writing to the file.

Comment: I don't really know the answer, but perhaps a temporary file is used, while the output is being written.

Comment: @vefthym the funny thing is that Flume is writing to a temp file:  it appends the destination file with (e.g. `abc.txt.tmp`) until it's completed writing.  We discussed the possibility that Flume is writing to a different temp file and then copying into `abc.txt.tmp` but that'd be rather weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is possibly due to the HDFS Coherency model.

While performing writes to HDFS, Once more than a block’s worth of data has been written, the first block will be visible to
new readers.
This is true of subsequent blocks, too: it is always the current block being
written that is not visible to other readers.

HDFS provides a way to force all buffers to be flushed to the datanodes via the hflush() method on FSDataOutputStream. After a successful return from hflush(), HDFS guarantees that the data written up to that point in the file has reached all the datanodes in the write pipeline and is visible to all new readers.
The statistics about the file like size etc are going to be available after successful completion of above process.

Comment: Thanks, we're going to test this out.  But is there a possibility that using `hflush()` will interfere with in progress writing?

Answer (score 2):

When using Azure blob storage, use **Page Blobs instead of Block Blobs** if `hflush()` guarantees are required.

CodeReaper's answer is correct. To elaborate with context in Azure, block blobs do not (predictably) implement `hflush()`: a call to `hflush()` actual flushes the SDK client buffer to an Azure in-memory store. The data is stored in this temporary cache for a default of 7 days, but is not accessible as a block blob until `sync()` or `close()` is called. `Page Blobs` do apparently guarantee that data is pushed to HDFS disk upon each `hflush()` call.

Comment: Interesting little wrinkle.  How did you find out this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

Hdfs calculates size based on lastblocklength report .In your scenario , i think you are still writing to hdfs and trying to get the size of the file and hdfs does not know how to calculate the size as it doest not have lastblocklength report .Try to use hflush after write which will solve this problem